# Springboot ServerConfig Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following in my app properties

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  config:
    uri: http://localhost:8890
```

I have this class:

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@Getter
public class Service {

  @Value("${Some Value}")
  Boolean val;
}
```

The problem, is that my app does not grab the configuration from the localhost running configuration server. I can tell you that my local config server is working fine and that the config is visible in a browser

Comment: If your class is a service, should you include the "@Service" annotation, above where you declare the class?

Comment: @acarlstein I tried both "@Service" and "@Confinguration". It does not seem to help.

Comment: mmmhhh, weird. How about `@Component`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added 'Spring cloud config client' dependency ?
And also add some properties in client service to make connection with config server ,

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888(Port of your 
                                                server)
spring.cloud.config.name=user-service-ws(properties file 
                                         name in your remote)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

Since spring boot 2.4 everything has changed. We must specify to bootstrap the cloud config. This is done using the dependency such as:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
 </dependency>


spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: myApp
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8890/
  cloud:
    config:
      name: some name
```

Very important to do this: optional:configserver:

Thanks everyone and hope it is useful to everyone.